# Killing or stopping an active thread

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gpio, omxplayer

I've come a long way and I'm almost there. I've converted from using Thread to Threading and can now switch videos mid-play, but I still am having trouble killing or stopping the first video. Basically, I'm making a video player controlled by buttons on a Raspberry Pi using OMXplayer. At the moment, I have to wait for one video to finish playing before pressing another button or else it will crash because multiple videos are playing at the same time.

Thanks so much for any help you guys can offer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
import threading
import time

GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings (False)

GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN)  # Button 1
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN) # Button 2

def shoppingcart():
        global current_video
        while True:
                if GPIO.input(9):
                        #current_video.terminate()
                        #current_video.kill()
                        print "Play Shoppingcart"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        current_video=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/shoppingcart.mp4'],
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)

def dodgeballs():
        global current_video
        while True:
                if GPIO.input(10):
                        #current_video.terminate()
                        #current_video.kill()
                        print "Play Dodgeballs"
                        time.sleep(1)
                        current_video=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/dodgeballs.mp4'],
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)

v1 = threading.Thread( name='shoppingcart', target=shoppingcart ) # Videos thread
v2 = threading.Thread( name='dodgeballs', target=dodgeballs )   # Videos thread

v1.start()
v2.start()

while True:
        pass

GPIO.cleanup() #Reset GPIOs
```

Comment: Use `thread.stop()`.

Comment: I read some of your code... Why not use the same thread? And there is no `thread.stop()` in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

Comment: I meant you could implement it by inheriting Thread and using a Boolean sentry.

Comment: Yup, you could... But I suppose the next thing he wants to do is open another thread. Why bother? :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani I just tried putting them in the same thread and I still need a way to stop the subprocess or video before the next video plays. I put them in separate threads because I was trying to kill the thread instead of the subprocess.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I'm trying it out right now. Fingers crossed I'm doing it correctly. Beginner in the house over here. hahaha

Comment: Yeah, I've posted the full code below if you want. See [here](http://repl.it/9Q2/1).

Comment: How did it go for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement your own threads:

```
class RaspberryThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.running = False
        self.function = function
        super(RaspberryThread, self).__init__()

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        super(RaspberryThread, self).start()

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.function()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
```

Then remove the while loops from your functions so you can pass them to the threads.

```
v1 = RaspberryThread(function = shoppingcart)
v2 = RaspberryThread(function = dodgeballs)

v1.start()
v2.start()
```

Then you can stop the threads at any time

```
v1.stop()
v2.stop()
```

Comment: I just restarted and still no video...so close! It will switch off between "Play Dodgeballs" and "Play Shoppingcarts" when I press each button though. I'll play around with omxplayer. It was working fine before, but never know. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I'm telling you it's a problem with your video player. Why don't you try playing it with Pygame?

Comment: I'll try that out. I had done that before, but switched to omxplayer because it seemed simpler.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else, but for know I recommend using a foolproof command line tool for playing the media.

Comment: I'll try. I have to run this with GPIO buttons controlling the videos. This is the only way I know how. If you know of another method definitely hit me up! Thanks! jmcclaire [at] gmail [dot] com

Comment: I recommend using a USB game controller that you can manipulate with Pygame, or just use the keyboard.

Comment: I'm building an interactive wall and the videos have to be controlled by arcade buttons that are already installed.

Comment: jmclaire, my code was actually flawed because I forgot to override the `start` method of threads. It should work correctly now, and it should play your videos with `omxplayer`.

Comment: @Malik Brahimi I also want to add an alive() function, but then I do this within the RaspberryThread class:
def alive(self):
      return super(TestThread, self).isAlive()

and then do:
v1.alive()
I get false. Do you know why?

Comment: @Malik Brahimi Never mind I figured out why there was a problem for the join.

One problem I do get by using the RaspberryThread is:

python(33400,0x700003b2b000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd2bea2fe00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

I think this problem comes up from the stop(), but I'm not too sure. I've been trying to debug for hours :/